# Why cant you throw from a destructor. Example

Tags: c++, exception, destructor

I have read that it is not a good idea to throw from a destructor because of stack unwinding. I am not sure I understand that fully. So I tried the following example

```
struct foo
{
    ~foo()
    {
        throw 1;
    }
};


struct bar
{
    ~bar()
    {
        throw 2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try 
    {
        foo a;
        bar b;
        throw 3;
    }catch(int a)
    {
        std::cout << a;
    }
}
```

Now I was expecting that the a would be 1 because first 3 is thrown then destructor of b is called which throws 2 and then destructor of a is called which throws 1. Apparently this is not the case and this might explain why its not a good idea to throw from destructors. My question is why was abort() called the destructor of b was called ?

Comment: Note that tin C++11 the default behaviour for destructors is to `terminate` on throwing an exception, even if no exception is active

Comment: @MattMcNabb I know you're right, but it bothers me that they made a breaking change like that.

Comment: I updated my answer significantly, I would probably not use ` std::uncaught_exception` and I added some references explaining why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you throw an exception while exception processing is ongoing, you get a special exception that can't be caught and this leads to an abort.

You can use [`std::uncaught_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception) to detect if exception handling is already in progress and avoid throwing in that case.

Comment: @MistyD I'm trying to follow that up with a more technical description but I can't remember the specific exception type.

Comment: Is there a good use for `uncaught_exception`? [Herb does not seem to think so](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm) but I have never thought about it so not really sure.

Comment: Nevermind I answered my own question, I added a link in my answer to a recent proposal to fix it by Herb and it explains how `ScopeGuard` uses the current version.

Answer (score 6):

Throwing an exception during *stack-unwinding* this will lead to `std::terminate` being called whose default action is to call `std::abort`.

[CERT](https://www.cert.org/) has a good explanation in their [ERR33-CPP. Destructors must not throw exceptions](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/ERR33-CPP.+Destructors+must+not+throw+exceptions) document which says (*emphasis mine*):

> A destructor is very likely to be called during stack unwinding
>   resulting from an exception being thrown. **If the destructor itself
>   throws an exception, having been called as the result of an exception
>   being thrown, then the function std::terminate() is called with the
>   default effect of calling std::abort()**. This could provide the
>   opportunity for a denial-of-service attack. Hence, destructors must
>   satisfy the no-throw guarantee, that is, they must not throw an
>   exception if they themselves have been called as the result of an
>   exception being thrown.

This is covered in the draft C++ standard section `15.2` *Constructors and destructors* which says:

> The process of calling destructors for automatic objects constructed
>   on the path from a try block to a throw-expression is called “stack
>   unwinding.” If a destructor called during stack unwinding exits with
>   an exception, std::terminate is called (15.5.1). [ Note: So
>   destructors should generally catch exceptions and not let them
>   propagate out of the destructor. —end note ]

Note that in C++11 destructors are specified implicitly `noexcept(true)` as long as none of the functions it calls allows exceptions. So in this case throwing from a destructor would call `std::terminate` regardless.

From section `12.4` *Destructors*:

> A declaration of a destructor that does not have an
>   exception-specification is implicitly considered to have the same
>   exception-specification as an implicit declaration (15.4).

and `15.4` says:

> An implicitly declared special member function (Clause 12) shall have
>   an exception-specification. If f is an implicitly declared default
>   constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, destructor, copy
>   assignment operator, or move assignment operator, its implicit
>   exception-specification specifies the type-id T if and only if T is
>   allowed by the exception-specification of a function directly invoked
>   by f’s implicit definition; f shall allow all exceptions if any
>   function it directly invokes allows all exceptions, and f **shall allow
>   no exceptions if every function it directly invokes allows no
>   exceptions.**

Theoretically you could use [std::uncaught_exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/uncaught_exception) to detect *stack-unwinding* in the destructor but in [GotW #47](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/047.htm) Herb Sutter explains why this technique is not as useful as it seems.

Although Herb has very recently proposed a fix in [N4152: uncaught
_exceptions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4152.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

On some cases it is possible to add an exception specification like this and handle them with safety. Note that the object is only deleted when no exception is thrown.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A{
    bool a;

    A():a(1){}
    ~A()throw(int){
        if(a)a=0,throw 0;
    }
};

int main(){
    A*a=new A();
    try{
        delete a;
    }catch(int&){
        delete a;
        cout<<"here"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `throw(int)` form of exception-specification is deprecated. Use `noexcept(false)` instead. (And never throw an `int`, use `std::exception`!)

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered from the standard, but I think another example illustrates the conceptual problem best:

```
struct foo {
    char *buf;

    foo() : buf(new char[100]) {}

    ~foo() {
        if(buf[0] == 'a')
            throw 1;
        delete[] buf;
    }
};

int main() {
    foo *f = new f;
    try {
        delete f;
    } catch(int a) {
        // Now what?
    }
}
```

This is a bit simplistic, of course, but shows the problem.  What's the right thing for `delete f` to have done?  Whichever way it goes, you end up with either a partially destructed object or a memory leak.